# foreach on parsing xml but shows only one record

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
foreach($xml1->results as $info) {
                    $title = $info->listing->title;
                    $favicon = $info->listing->favicon;


                    echo $favicon;
                    echo "<a href=".$redirect;
                    echo ">".$title."</a><BR>";

                }
```

The output is all fine, but only showing one record.  What could be the problem.

XML Structure

```
<listing>
   <title></title>
   <url></url>
   <description>[result-description]</description>
</listing>
```

Comment: try foreach($xml1->results[0] as $info) {}

Comment: It shows more than one results without a title, favicon

Comment: could you give the structure of the xml?

Comment: Try with `foreach($xml1->results->info as $info)`. If that works, its a common duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Your code and question suggests that the $xml contains a tag at least two tags "results".

The simplexml ignores the root tag as being part of the object, it only includes the attributes.

so, if your xml looks like

```
<results>
    <listing>
        <title></title>
        <favicon></favicon>
    </listing>
    <listing>
        <title></title>
        <favicon></favicon>
    </listing>
</results>
```

the code should be

```
foreach($xml1->listing as $info)
```

Comment: You have to invoke results to get the listings

Comment: if results is the root I might be wrong on this one but as far as I know, you don't.. try Roel Veldhuizen's method...

Comment: @catalin did try, but the results do not appear.  I have to invoke the results->listing->xxx for the title and favicon to appear.  Does not appear with just $xml1->listing

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<results>
    <listing>
        <title>title 1</title>
        <favicon>fav1</favicon>
    </listing>
    <listing>
        <title>title 2</title>
        <favicon>fav2</favicon>
    </listing>
</results>
";


$xmlObj=simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xmlObj as $info){
    $title = $info->title;
    $favicon = $info->favicon;


    echo $favicon;
    echo "<a href=''";
    echo ">".$title."</a><BR>";

}
```

Comment: Sorry..its just not coming in, not sure how without getting into results you are invoking listing

Comment: just copy and paste the above in a php file and you'll see it works :)

Comment: as you can see in the example on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php the root tag is not accessed as the object IS the root tag. The same logic is applied to the listing tag, iterating through the listing tags loads each one in the $info variable